Is there a way to find all occurences of std::vector<bool> in my code?
I manage a big complex code with a lot of template classes.
I would like to forbid usage of std::vector<bool> in the code (because this is a recurrent and painful cause of compilation problems). I can grep std::vector<bool>, but I can't find easily when templates classes used in other templaces classes instanciate template vectors which turns out to be vectors of bool.
Is there a gcc warning, or a tool, or a trick to find the cases where the code instantiate a std::vector<bool> ?

What platform is this on?

@PaulFloyd I work with gcc 13 on Ubuntu 24.

Also look for std::vector<T> (or other template arguments you use) and either add SFINAE/Concepts or static_assert into those template classes (that T is not bool). That should give you compilation errors (and prevent them from ever being added to code again)

@PepijnKramer static_assert for each std::vector is a good idea to find them. But it doesn't prevent future usage by other devs. But it's better than nothing.

I initially meant template classes that have std::vector members (that will prevent them from specializing on bool in the future too)

With clang tooling, you might get AST and search for instantiation of std::vector<bool>, if a search for vector<T>/vector<bool>/other possible variant with typedef for either bool or vector is too painful/error prone.

Try: nm -C /path/to/your/compiled/binary | c++filt | grep "std::vector<bool," - didn't test this

@MarekR I was thinking on the same lines. No need for -C amd c++filt, and you can do this on object files as well to narrow down the seatch.

Had a similar regulation that disallows developers to use std::unordered_map<SomeClass> for data that are bound to be iterated and while the order must be preserved.
It is achieved by changing stl code to something like specializing the template and delete the constructors by all means:
std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >
vector() = delete;

And regularly rebuild the software with the customized GCC together to do static check.
If you found it's difficult to find which part of stl src to change, you can always break at the function in GDB, then you'll know where it is defined.

you should be more clear about doing the change in the standard lib, because trying to do this in user code wont do any good

Seems more a (one-shot) hack to find current problematic spots.

Exactly, it must be confined to be a special internal check. No one wants to modify the GCC used to build release :(

Providing an own version of <vector> and playing with include paths might be cleaner and reusable in UTs.
